# DNS Check with multiple domains and IPs

Tags: bash, unix, dns

I am building a script which checks for various potential issues on servers and I have a section where it should check all domains on the server against a dig for that server and checks if the domain is pointed to the server's IP.

All commands work as expected when run independently but the script outputs the domain as being checked against only one IP.

Here is the relevant part of the script:

```
checkDomainDNS()    {                                   
if [ "$controlPanelVersion" == "Plesk" ]; then
serverIPs=()
for ips in $(ifconfig | grep "inet addr:" | cut -d":" -f2 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | grep -v '127.0.0.*\|0.0.0.0\|3.0.13.6');do
let count++
serverIPs[count - 1]+=$ips
done
    domainsArray=()
        for domain in $(MYSQL_PWD=`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` mysql -u admin -Dpsa -e"SELECT dom.id, dom.name, ia.ipAddressId, iad.ip_address FROM domains dom LEFT JOIN DomainServices d ON (dom.id = d.dom_id AND d.type = 'web') LEFT JOIN IpAddressesCollections ia ON ia.ipCollectionId = d.ipCollectionId LEFT JOIN IP_Addresses iad ON iad.id = ia.ipAddressId" | cut -d"|" -f3 | awk '{print $2}'); do
        let count++
        domainsArray[count - 1]+=$domain
        done
            for domain in ${domainsArray[*]};do
                dnsResult=()
                for dnsResult in $(dig A $domain | grep $domain | awk '{print $5}' | grep -v "<<>>" | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v "ns");do
                let count++
                dnsResult[count - 1]+=$dnsResult
                done
            done
                for i in ${serverIPs[*]};do
                    if [ "$dnsResult" == "$ips[*]" ]; then
                        echo "$domain is pointed correctly" >> $reportlog
                    elif [ "$dnsResult" != "$ips[*]" ]; then
                        echo "$domain is not pointed to $ips" >> $reportlog
                    fi
                done
fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the future here is the resolution:

```
checkDomainDNS()    {

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                echo "Checking domain DNS records"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                if [ "$controlPanelVersion" == "Plesk" ]; then
                                                                    domainsArray=()
        for domain in $(MYSQL_PWD=`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` mysql -u admin -Dpsa -e"SELECT dom.id, dom.name, ia.ipAddressId, iad.ip_address FROM domains dom LEFT JOIN DomainServices d ON (dom.id = d.dom_id AND d.type = 'web') LEFT JOIN IpAddressesCollections ia ON ia.ipCollectionId = d.ipCollectionId LEFT JOIN IP_Addresses iad ON iad.id = ia.ipAddressId" | cut -d"|" -f3 | awk '{print $2}' | grep -Ev "name"); do
                                                                let count++
                                                                domainsArray[count - 1]+=$domain
                                                                done
                                                                serverIPs=()
                                                       for ips in $(ifconfig | grep "inet addr:" | cut -d":" -f2 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | grep -v '127.0.0.*\|0.0.0.0\|3.0.13.6');do
                                                                        let count++
                                                                        serverIPs[count - 1]+=$ips
                                                                        done
                                                                            for domain in ${domainsArray[*]};do
                                                                            pointing="no"
                                                                            dnsResult=$(dig A $domain | grep $domain | awk '{print $5}' | grep -v "<<>>" | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v "ns")
                                                                            for i in ${serverIPs[*]};do
                                                                            if [ "$dnsResult" == "$i" ]; then
                                                                            pointing="yes"
                                                                            break
                                                                            fi
                                                                            done
                                                                        if [ $pointing == "no" ]; then
                                                                            echo "$domain is not pointed towards this server" >> $reportlog
                                                                        fi
                                                                        done
                                                          else
                                                          echo "Checking dns only works on Plesk servers" >> $reportlog
                                                        fi
}
```